# Server side data fetching

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to set up a basic component that is rendered on the server and the client. The component is populated with data from a JSON API. I've got this working on the client-side by loading my data in componentDidMount and calling this.setState when it has loaded.

The problem I have is that the data isn't loaded on the server. How do I get the initial data into the server-rendered version of my component?

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/latest/docs/guides/advanced/ServerRendering.md is very vague about this:

> For data loading, you can use the renderProps argument to build
>   whatever convention you want--like adding static load methods to your
>   route components, or putting data loading functions on the
>   routes--it's up to you.

Do you have an example anywhere of how to do this? It seems like a very basic thing for a universal application to want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup - we have https://github.com/rackt/async-props that provides a library for dealing with async data between server and client, and provides an example for doing so. If you're using a Flux framework, you'll want to make appropriate adjustments, but the basic approach will be quite similar.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked well. Just need a fundamental bug-fix to ship for client-side hydrating :-) https://github.com/rackt/async-props/issues/4